# Dash Gauges not on until I press the brakes then they come on

Tags: jeep

I have a 2003 Jeep Wrangler and dash gauges will not come on unless I press the brake pedal. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the connectors on back of IC and also check its grounds.

Comment: Welcome.  I am at a loss, however I would check out the wiring especially near the instrument cluster, moving it slightly with your hands and see if the cluster comes to life.  @narkelepth and I are in agreement.  Good luck.  You may likely find a loose connector.